# Variable size label issue in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a form using Bootstrap but my labels are of variable size which are causing my form to get distorted as marked in the screenshot.

I have used `clearfix` class & `vertical-align` style as well.

I don't want fixed height for my labels as they can of varying size. (e.g. 2, 3, 4 or even of more lines).

This is my code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Label 1 </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Label 2 In fact the bigger label than all </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Label 3 </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Label 4 </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Label 5 </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Label 6 </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: Please post what you have already tried.

Comment: Not seeing any issue: http://codeply.com/go/YAiebQSr6v

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it when forced to use bootstrap

Within your input 'row' you have an 'input-label' and 'input-element' which are col-6. This ensures that they take up 50% of the available space. The col-xs-12 ensures that they then stack at smaller browser widths (mobile).

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 input-label">
                 <label for="xxx">Input label</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 input-element">
                <input type="text" name="xxx" id="xxx" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanx Pat for the suggestion but what I want is to logically group more than 6 to 10 fields in a single row so as to achieve the effect of 3 Cols for large screens, 2 cols for Medium screens & 1 col for small screens. Is there a generic class which aligns input fields to the bottom or at the line of one which is pulled down due to variable height of label???

Comment: @shrriamkure - CSS : vertical-align: top; or vertical-align: bottom;